# Why safecopy won't recover to /media/?

Tags: files, data-recovery, file-copy, safecopy

I tried to recover an HDD to a mounted device:

```
safecopy --stage1 /dev/sdb3 /media/Volume/abc
```

and it says `Error opening destination: /media/Volume/abc is a directory`.

If I run `safecopy` with

```
safecopy --stage1 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sdc1
```

it starts working. But after finishing this process, I can't open the destination.

It should simply copy all files from the bad HDD to the new HDD
(not cloning, just copy the data), so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You first create an image with:

```
safecopy --stage1 /dev/sdb3 output.img
```

and so a file called `output.img` will be created as an intermediate step.
Then

```
dd if=output.img of=/media/Volume/abc
```

for copying the image to partition of the new HDD.

The destination in your `safecopy` command has to be a file!

Answer (score 0):

You are providing the mountpoint directory `/media/Volume/abc` when a file or device must be provided.
Given that you are providing a mountpoint, you seem to want to provide a device.
To find out the device that's mounted to a mountpoint, `mount` or `findmnt` can be used.